# multiple prices 1 item

Tags: database

I'm wondering if this would be the best way to build a table for an item that can have more than 1 price. Each product is identified by its model_number. Should I use a prefix before the model_number for each individual seller? I can't use model_number for the primary key. For example:

```
seller_product_id      model_number     seller      price
SELLER_1_MODEL_NUMBER  MODEL_NUMBER     seller_1    9.99
SELLER_2_MODEL_NUMBER  MODEL_NUMBER     seller_2    19.99
```

Comment: Which type of database is this on? Also I recently updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of loose coupling, I suggest you build seperate `Items` and `Price` tables, and have another [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) (called [Junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)) `Item_Price` which maps many items to many prices as you like.

This is called [Many-to-Many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29)

Basically, it links an `Item` with its itemId to a `Price` with priceId, and stores this link in an `Item_Price` itemPriceId (or whatever you call the 3rd primary key)

Here's a sample diagram EDIT: sorry about the previous diagram.
[image]

Here's a sample SQL DDL of 3 tables, plus 2 junction tables to associate Item to Price, and Seller to Item.

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
    item_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    ..
    ..
)

CREATE TABLE Price (
    price_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    ..
    ..
)

CREATE TABLE Seller (
    seller_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    ..
    ..
)

-- This is the junction table for Item to Price mapping.
CREATE TABLE Item_Price (
    item_id int REFERENCES Item (item_id),
    price_id int REFERENCES Price (price_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id, price_id)
)

-- This is the junction table for Seller to Item mapping.
CREATE TABLE Seller_Item (
    seller_id int REFERENCES Seller (seller_id),
    item_id int REFERENCES Item (item_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (seller_id, item_id)
)
```

Comment: Is the seller table necessary?

Comment: @RPM It's your decision to make. It's better to seperate each entity to cohesive tables. Storing `Seller` code in an `Item` record row is not a good practice. Let's assume you did that. What will you do if you need to change a seller's code? Will you also update all of the items that seller sells?

Answer (score 2):

One attribute that have many properties? Sounds like `one-to-many` relations... go for a new table have foreign key help you out.

```
Products
prod_id (PK) | model_no

Sellers
seller_id(PK)|seller_name

Pricing
price_id (PK)|price|prod_id (FK) | seller_id(FK)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes You can a prefix before the model_number for each individual seller.

If you still have stuff then let me know more clear your problem